Not retrieving refresh token from google, using auth0 react
I have followed all the steps when setting up auth0 google social connections.
I am having trouble receiving a refresh token from google using the auth0 react hook, Auth0Provider.
Here is my Auth0Provider hook.
    <Auth0Provider
    domain=DOMAIN
    clientId=CLIENT_ID
    authorizationParams={{
      redirect_uri: `http://localhost:3000/home`,
      connection_scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
      access_type: 'offline', 
      approvalPrompt: 'consent'
    }}>
        <App />
      </Auth0Provider>

I retrieve only the following from the user identities section.
  {
    expires_in: 3599,
    access_token:ACCESS_TOKEN,
    connection: 'google-oauth2',
    user_id: USER_ID,
    provider: 'google-oauth2',
    isSocial: true
  }

